# How to serialize a sequence of 'Any' elements without a containing element

Tags: c#, serialization, xsd

I need to serialize some data to pass as a message over a web service which will validate the data against a schema. I have built an object model but I'm missing something in one small area.

This is the schema:

```
<xs:element name="UserDetailsMessage" minOccurs="0">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="URDUSERDETAILS" minOccurs="0">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:any processContents="skip" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

This is my class:

```
[Serializable()] public class UserDetailsMessage
{
    private USERDETAILS myUserDetails;

    [XmlElementAttribute("USERDETAILS")]
    public USERDETAILS USERDETAILS {
        get {
            if (myUserDetails == null)
                myUserDetails = new USERDETAILS();
            return this.myUserDetails;
        }
        set { this.myUserDetails = value; }
    }

    public bool URDUSERDETAILSSpecified {
        get {
            if (myUserDetails == null)
                return false;
            return true;
        }
    }

}

[Serializable()] public class USERDETAILS
{
    private List<System.Xml.XmlElement> anyField;

    [XmlAnyElementAttribute(), XmlElementAttribute("Any")]
    public List<System.Xml.XmlElement> Any {
        get { return this.anyField; }
        set { this.anyField = value; }
    }

}
```

I am using an `XmlElementAttribute` on the `Any` element in order to get it to serialize as a sequence of elements without a container, however the XML output isn't coming out as I thought it would:

```
<UserDetailsMessage>
    <USERDETAILS>
        <Any>
            <TEST_DATA_HERE />
        </Any>
    </USERDETAILS>
</UserDetailsMessage>
```

Which causes the `XmlDocument.Validate` method to output this validation error: `The 'Any' element is not declared`

As far as I know the output I'm trying to create should look like this:

```
<UserDetailsMessage>
    <USERDETAILS>
        <TEST_DATA_HERE />
    </USERDETAILS>
</UserDetailsMessage>
```

Is the `XmlElementAttribute` interacting with the `XmlAnyElementAttribute` in some way to produce this output or have I made an obvious mistake somewhere? Alternatively, how should I serialize a sequence of 'Any' elements without a containing element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally had time to sit down and create  test project with only the specific area of concern and arrived at the following.

```
<Serializable()> Public Class NotificationMessage

    Private myUserData As UserData

    Public Sub New()
        myUserData = New UserData()
    End Sub

    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("UserData")> _
    Public Property UserData() As UserData
        Get
            Return Me.myUserData
        End Get
        Set(value As UserData)
            Me.myUserData = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class

<Serializable()> Public Class UserData

    Private anyField As List(Of System.Xml.XmlElement)

    Public Sub New()
        Me.anyField = New List(Of System.Xml.XmlElement)()
    End Sub

    <XmlAnyElementAttribute()>
    Public Property Any() As List(Of System.Xml.XmlElement)
        Get
            Return Me.anyField
        End Get
        Set(value As List(Of System.Xml.XmlElement))
            Me.anyField = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

This is the output if `XmlElement` and `XmlAnyElement` are combined and applied to the Any property of the UserData class:

```
<NotificationMessage>
  <UserData>
    <Any>
      <TEST_DATA_HERE />
    </Any>
  </UserData>
</NotificationMessage>
```

This is the output if only the `XmlElement` is applied:

```
<NotificationMessage>
  <UserData>
    <Any>
      <TEST_DATA_HERE />
    </Any>
  </UserData>
</NotificationMessage>
```

This is the output with only the `XmlAnyElement` applied:

```
<NotificationMessage>
  <UserData>
    <TEST_DATA_HERE />
  </UserData>
</NotificationMessage>
```

So we can see that in order to serialize a sequence of 'Any' elements we must use **only** the XmlAnyElement attribute on its own.